# 'No parameterless constructor defined for type SiteResourceGraphType' message, when injecting repository into SiteResourceGraphType

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, graphql-dotnet, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have a `SiteResourceGraphType` class, which is inherited from `ObjectGraphType`. `SiteResourceGraphType` class accepts `IGenericRepository<Site, Guid>` in order to resolve `items` field.

When I start my application, I'm getting error 'No parameterless constructor defined for type SiteResourceGraphType'.

**Startup**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ServiceDbContext>(options => options
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("GraphQLServiceDatabase"));

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));

        services.AddScoped<IServiceProvider>(x => new FuncServiceProvider(type => x.GetRequiredService(type)));
        services.AddScoped<GraphQLServiceSchema>();
        services.AddScoped<SiteResourceGraphType>();
        services.AddScoped<SiteGraphType>();
        services.AddScoped<LocationGraphType>();
        services.AddScoped<LocationInputGraphType>();

        services
            .AddGraphQL(x =>
            {
                x.ExposeExceptions = true;
            })
            .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
            .AddDataLoader();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseGraphQL<GraphQLServiceSchema>();
        app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());
    }
}
```

**Schema**

```cs
public class GraphQLServiceSchema : Schema
{
    public GraphQLServiceSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        Query = (IObjectGraphType) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(GraphQLServiceQuery));
        Mutation = (IObjectGraphType) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(GraphQLServiceMutation));
    }
}
```

**Query**
I have used *Query Organization* technique from [graphql-dotnet docs](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/query-organization)

```cs
public class GraphQLServiceQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public GraphQLServiceQuery()
    {
        Field<SiteResourceGraphType>("sites", resolve: context => new { });
    }
}
```

**Target GraphType**

```cs
public class SiteResourceGraphType : ObjectGraphType
{
    public SiteResourceGraphType(IGenericRepository<Site, Guid> siteRepository)
    {
        Field<StringGraphType>("resourceCode",
            resolve: context => { return "RCODE1"; });

        Field<ListGraphType<SiteGraphType>>("items",
            resolve: context => siteRepository.GetAll());
    }
}
```

The purpose of this `SiteResourceGraphType` is to provide response structure like this:

```
{
   "sites": {
        "resourceCode": "CODE1",
        "items": [...]
    },
    ...
}
```

I've reviewed a lot of posts from stackoverflow, github about DI in graphql-dotnet, I've tried different versions of this library (right now I'm using "3.0.0-preview-1271" version).

But still the issue about parameterless ctor remains.
I'm really tired figuring out what I am missing. Please help!

Comment: Did you try to add a parameterless ctor to SiteResourceGraphType?

Comment: Yes, the app started successfully, but another ctor with repository is not called at all. That is the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I must to apologize for this post. The issue was on my side in external service, which registers my GraphQL service. I couldn't figure out this, since the error didn't point to external service and that was not obvious for me.

Comment: haha that was my next assumption :p
usually when it says some error about the parameterless constructor, it's because it wasn't able to find a constructor that matches the Services available in the collection.
So you should check the dependecies (on constructors) and recheck the services.

happy to see that you found out!

Comment: This answer is terrible. What was the solution?